# Do u start with db design or domain objects design in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Do the db design(tables) need to address concerns other than persistence of the domain model??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) (*Domain*-Driven Design) states that you are going to drive your design from Domain. Thus you don't care of database design (tables) - you are [persistence ignorant](http://thinkddd.com/glossary/persistence-ignorance/).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, DDD places the focus on the model while abstracting data access with persistence ignorance. I find this appropriate, however once you begin to design your aggregate roots and entities, it is difficult to escape data access concerns. Your entities may end up looking slightly different depending on whether you go for traditional SQL persistence, a document store, or event sourcing. The modeling process should be persistence agnostic and focus on the business domain alone leaving architectural concerns out. Take a look at this thread for discussion: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/domaindrivendesign/message/23106